# Prevent browser opening anchor link in new tab with left click while holding control key

Tags: html, css, gwt, browser

In the application I am working on we use GWT and there is a widget which contains list of items. Each item row is represented by an anchor `<a>` element. I would like to add functionality when clicking the row/element while holding `Ctrl` key would do something else as when clicked without  any key pressed (sort of like selection).

This works as expected in Chrome. However Mozilla and maybe IE (I don't know I use Linux) always opens a new tab and I cannot get rid of it.

This is the html code:

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:;">... content ...</a>
```

Setting `href` to empty string does not seem to work.It just opens the ULR of the current page in new tab.

What can I do to prevent this annoying behaviour?

Comment: You shouldn't change expected browser behaviour or take control away from the user like that. Very poor UX in my opinion.

Comment: Actually it is not changing of the browser behavior. Ideally the widget would have been implemented by other elements than anchors but that would be time consuming to code widget by our selves.

Comment: You're trying to **prevent** (your word) the browser from doing something it does normally aren't you? Anyway, it's just an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution inside GWT code.

```
ClickEvent.preventDefault()
```

seems to stop the event from being propagated to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> `href="javascript:;"`

If it's not a link, don't use a link (`<a>`).

If it's a widget, use a `FocusWidget` (e.g. `InlineLabel` or `InlineHTML`) instead of an `Anchor`; if you're using event delegation, then just use a `<span>` instead of the `<a>` (and add styling to make it look like a link if you like confusing your users).

Comment: The problem that the widget uses it internally. Only other option is coding our own widget with the same  look and feel.